# Script executes slower on different servers

Tags: performance, iis, vbscript, asp-classic, database-performance

This is just a question to have some ideas of where I am doing it wrong. 
I have a classic ASP application deployed on two environments (Test and Integration). The problem is that on the Test environment it takes about 10 seconds to load a certain page, as on the INT environment, the same page, takes about one minute. The difference between them is that I have different databases for Test and INT and that on the Test environment there is one server but on the INT environment there are two servers that are doing some balancing.

Also, on my ASP page I use the Response.Buffer property, but there is not Response.Flush() or Response.Clear() method called on the page. Maybe this is also a problem, but I am not sure.

Any ideas from where this delay may come from ?

Unfortunately this is all the code that I can share.

Thank you

Comment: Share your ASP code please.

Comment: @omegastripes I have added the code, I do not know how much it will help :)

Comment: Same data volume, same database structure (including indexes)? Can be the INT server under a heavier load than the DEV one? Is the INT database in another network?

Comment: @RubensFarias the databases are identical from the structure point of view. On the INT server indeed there are more users than on the TEST and also the INT database is in another network.

Answer (score 0):

what is the page doing, reading from a database?

if it is, you should run the querys directly in the databases first and if they are as fast, start thinking about IIS or ASP as the problem. If not the problem is at the databases and asp has nothing to do with it.